# Each cells of TableView is populated with same set of data

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I have got a uitableview with custom cells.

In `cellForRowAtIndexPath` method, im fetching values from core data and displaying it.

It has to display datas uniquely but the problem is that each cells of tableview are displaying the same set of data.

Following is my `cellForRowAtIndexPath`method,

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

    UITableViewCell *cell = nil;
    cell = (UITableViewCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@""];

    if (cell == nil)
    {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault
                                      reuseIdentifier:nil];
        cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryDisclosureIndicator;
    }



    self.productAmountTextLabel = [[UILabel alloc]init];

    NSManagedObject *device = [self.devices objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    self.productAmountTextLabel.text = [device valueForKey:@"amount"];
    self.productAmountTextLabel.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"HelveticaNeue" size:10];


    tableView.tableFooterView = [UIView new];

    cell.layer.borderWidth = 1.0;
    cell.layer.cornerRadius = 10;
    cell.layer.borderColor = [UIColor blackColor].CGColor;



    [cell.contentView addSubview:self.productAmountTextLabel];
    return cell;
}
```

the amount label fetches only the first value from db and displays the first value in all cells. How can I sort this out?

Comment: Do not reference the label with an ivar, just use a local variable, also do not create the footer inside this mathod

Comment: can you please elaborate with reference to my code? thank you

Comment: You can directly use cell.textLabel instead of self.productAmountTextLabel

Comment: Or create a custom table view cell and create your label in it and use that. Issue is with your label declared globally

Comment: `cell.productAmountTextLabel` is not  possible since  property `productAmountTextLabel` is not found on object of type `UITableView`

Comment: UITableViewCell have a default UILabel in it. Try cell.textLabel

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This problem generally occurs when u make a mistake in returning values for rows and section

Check your this code

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    // Return the number of sections.
    return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return [self.devices count];

}
```

Probably u have returned the values vice-versa

Comment: yeah..i debugged it by logging

Answer (score 0):

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

    UITableViewCell *cell = nil;
    cell = (UITableViewCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"any-cell"];

    if (cell == nil)
    {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault
                                      reuseIdentifier:@"any-cell"];
        cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryDisclosureIndicator;

        cell.layer.borderWidth = 1.0;
        cell.layer.cornerRadius = 10;
        cell.layer.borderColor = [UIColor blackColor].CGColor;

        UILabel* productAmountTextLabel = [[UILabel alloc]init];
        productAmountTextLabel.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"HelveticaNeue" size:10];
        productAmountTextLabel.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 100, 30); // for example
        productAmountTextLabel.tag = 10000; // any number
        [cell.contentView addSubview:productAmountTextLabel];
    }

    // tableView.tableFooterView = [UIView new];

    UILabel* lbl = (UILabel*)[cell.contentView viewWithTag: 10000];
    NSManagedObject *device = [self.devices objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    lbl.text = [device valueForKey:@"amount"];
    return cell;
}

- (void) makeFooter {
    myTableView.tableFooterView = [UIView new];
}
```

Comment: i tried it but still the same problem is persisting

Comment: i tried logging     `NSLog(@"%@",[device valueForKey:@"amount"]);` and it prints only one value which is the first value

Comment: I think your array is not proper

Comment: NSLog(@"ds %@",amountArray); contains two unique values

Comment: Please check the value of "self.devices" and "[device valueForKey:@"amount"]"

Answer (score 0):

Try this code

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

    UITableViewCell *cell = nil;
    cell = (UITableViewCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"Cell"];

    if (cell == nil)
    {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault
                                      reuseIdentifier:@"Cell"];
        cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryDisclosureIndicator;
    }

    NSManagedObject *device = [self.devices objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    cell.textLabel.text = [device valueForKey:@"amount"];
    cell.textLabel.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"HelveticaNeue" size:10];

    cell.layer.borderWidth = 1.0;
    cell.layer.cornerRadius = 10;
    cell.layer.borderColor = [UIColor blackColor].CGColor;

    return cell;
}
```

Issue might be with the global UILabel which you are using. If you want any customizations in your label, then create a custom UITableViewCell class and declare the label in it. Use your class instead of UITableViewCell while declaring cell

Comment: still the same problem persists bro.

Comment: Can you check the values in your self.devices array are proper or not?

Comment: the values in self.devices array are proper but `NSLog(@"%@",[device valueForKey:@"amount"]); ` prints only one value twice since there are two cells